# Running Backup on single DB when scheduled job (USER_DATABASES) has failed

Tags: backup, ola-hallengren

I'm using Ola Hallengren's sp to take backup of database.
FULL DIFF and LOG backup is created with respective schedules (agent job) and has been working great.

Due to not enough free disk space on backup disk one database did not get backed up.
I've expanded drive to accommodate growing databases but now wondering how to take full backup of that one database with out affecting backup chain ?

Tried this on test server

```
use db1
exec [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'db2', 
    @Directory = N'pathtobackup', 
    @BackupType = 'FULL',
    @Verify = 'Y',
    @CleanupTime = 168,
    @CheckSum = 'Y'
```

and backup went fine ....until I tried to do restore which gave me (as I suspected) this error : Unable to create restore plan due to break in the LSN chain.

So my question is how to run single FULL backup on one DB that is a part of scheduled FULL backup run by agent with out destroying existing chain?

Thanks

Comment: You have to restart the log backup chain from scratch using a full backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `@CopyOnly` parameter to the procedure to take a copy only full backup and not break the log chain.

> A copy-only backup is a SQL Server backup that is independent of the
>   sequence of conventional SQL Server backups. Usually, taking a backup
>   changes the database and affects how later backups are restored.
>   However, occasionally, it is useful to take a backup for a special
>   purpose without affecting the overall backup and restore procedures
>   for the database. Copy-only backups serve this purpose.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

[Copy only parameter on Ola's website](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)

**Example**

```
use db1
exec [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'db2', 
    @Directory = N'pathtobackup', 
    @BackupType = 'FULL',
    @Verify = 'Y',
    @CleanupTime = 168,
    @CheckSum = 'Y',
    @CopyOnly = 'Y'
```

Comment: I am aware of @CopyOnly  but does that enables me to use DIFF backup  files created before single FULL backup error and does it give me option to use "point in time" restore (with SSMS) combined with DIFF as I mentioned before ?

What I am trying to achieve is to create extraordinary FULL back that can use existing DIFF Files created days before.(if this makes sense)

Comment: @CoWr You will need the original full backup to apply diff + log backups to it. It is only possible with that full backup, you cannot create a full backup now to go back in time.